# How to add Table row to the select box Element using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having a simple HTML table with dynamic data generated from Server side. The table contains several rows with 2 columns  and a check box .click the check box for each row and clicking "ADD" button the rows should get added to the select box  in this format 
"row1col1value:row1col2value:". The select box should only contain the rows which are checked

[sample code in this link](http://jsfiddle.net/6nT2r/16/)

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/6nT2r/16/][2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $('#myselect').empty();
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        var _row_data = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function(){
           return $(this).html();
        }).get().join('');
        $('#myselect').append('<option>' + _row_data + '</option>');
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/g3CZC/

Comment: @allein: In my form there are many radio buttons and check boxes  so the results of those check boxes are radio buttons are also appeneded to the select element. In the code  it means $(':checked').each(function(){  .Here i need to select  the rows  that are checked in this table

Comment: Here is What to select the table rows which are checked $('#MyTable td input:checked)each(function(){ instead of $(':checked').each(function(){

Comment: Nah just change `$(':checked').each` to `$(':checkbox:checked').each`

Answer (score 1):

Here my attempt

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#myselect").empty();
    var values;
    $("input:checked").parent("td").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings("td").each(function(index) {
            if (index == 0) values = $(this).text() + ":";
            else values = values + $(this).text();
        });
        $("#myselect").append("<option>" + values + "</option>");
    });

})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6nT2r/27/

Comment: :In my form there are many radio buttons and check boxes so the results of those check boxes are radio buttons are also appeneded to the select element. In the code it means $(':checked').each(function(){ .Here i need to select the rows that are checked in this table

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("addButtonSelector").click(function(){

   var str = "";
   $("tableSelector tr").each(function(i){
     if($(this).find("input:checked").length){
       str = str + "row"+(i+1)+ $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text() + ":";
     } 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
  $('#myselect').html(
  $(':checked').map(function () {
    var selText = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function () {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(':');
    return $('<option>', { text: selText }).get();
  }));
});
```

[Customary jsFiddle Link.](http://jsfiddle.net/6nT2r/40/)

The most important thing to take away from this example is the [Map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) idiom. Notice how I transform the set of checked elements into the option elements I need and then just replace the html of my target select.